# How to "add vert" in blender 2.8?

Tags: mesh, vertices, shortcut

I'm following a tutorial called "Fuel Station - Blender 2.8 Low Poly 3D Modeling Tutorial", and the teacher is adding a vertex typing "Shift+A" that show a Mesh Submenu -> Single Vert -> Add Single Vert, just like this:
[image]

The problem is: when I try to make the same, it only shows this:
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Add a cube and remove all other 7 verts?

Comment: Hi @Leander, I don't think that's a good choice, it can be much more simple. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 10):

Just solved it. You need to install the add on. Go to Edit -> Preferences, type extra in the search box at Add-ons submenu, select both add-ons and install them. Just like this:
[image]